# Can Events be declared as Static, if yes how and why

Tags: c#

I want to know can we declare the events as static if yes why and application of such declaration.

Sample please as seeing is believing

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You can create static events.  You use them the same way as a normal event, except that it's used in a static context within the class.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static event EventHandler MyEvent;
    private static void RaiseEvent()
    {
        MyEvent?.Invoke(typeof(MyClass), EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

That being said, there are many issues with static events.  You must take extra care to unsubscribe your objects from static events, since a subscription to a static event will root your subscribing instance, and prevent the garbage collector from ever collecting it.

Also, I've found that most cases where I'd want to make static events, I tend to learn towards using a standard event on a [Singleton](https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Singleton) instead.  This handles the same scenarios as a static event, but is (IMO) more obvious that you're subscribing to a "global" level instance.

Comment: Small question: "subscribing instance" refers to the subject or to the observer? It's only one of them that is being rooted?

Answer (score 11):

Yes, you can. See, for example, [Application.ApplicationExit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.applicationexit.aspx). Note, however, the warnings on that page about memory leaks when attaching to static events; that applies to all static events.

There's nothing magical about when you use them: when you need to provide an event for a static class or an event that deals exclusively with static data and it makes sense to implement it this way.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can declare an event as static. You use them the same way you would use them if they were instance events, but you access the event name in a static way (i.e. `ClassName.EventName`, rather than `variableName.EventName`).

Now... do you *want* static events? That's highly debatable. I personally would say no, since static anything creates difficulties in testing and should thus be avoided whenever possible.

But it's certainly possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
public delegate void SomeEventDelegate();

public class SomeClass
{
        public static event SomeEventDelegate SomeEvent;
}
```